# Camera passthrough in QEMU/KVM (linux) guest machine

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, usb-device

I try to get the camera working in my qemu (Archlinux) guest machine. The host is also an Archlinux system.

Below I show the command I tried and the `lsusb` and `lspci` outputs.
When I start the guest system I get 2 warnings about the 2 cameras I have connected (lenovo built-in, Trust usb-plugged).

I found a article which apparently explains the cause [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564708/qemu-kvm-virt-manager-passthrough-of-usb-webcam-to-windows-7-enterprise-creates) but I can figure out what I exactly should do.

> This problem is caused because the virtual USB hubs default to USB 1.1
>   - if you change it to USB 2 before launching the VM the camera should appear ok. But USB 3+ devices still cause problems.

---

```
- command to start the qemu machine:
```

`$sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -smp 6 -m 4G -enable-kvm -vga std -soundhw ac97\
-usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=11 -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=3,hostaddr=1 -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=3,hostaddr=2 -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=2,hostaddr=1 -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=1 -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=2 -usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=3 -k en-uk -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user -drive file=qemu-drive,format=raw`

```
- warnings:
```

`qemu-system-x86_64: Warning: speed mismatch trying to attach usb device "Lenovo EasyCamera" (high speed) to bus "usb-bus.0", port "2.6" (full speed)`

`qemu-system-x86_64: Warning: speed mismatch trying to attach usb device "Trust Webcam" (high speed) to bus "usb-bus.0", port "1" (full speed)`

---

```
lsusb
```

`Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04d9:a029 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 145f:019f Trust 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

```
lspci
```

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
09:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
0a:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)`

Comment: Would you be opposed to using Virtual Machine Manager and libvirt?  I've done this successfully with Arch host and guest without problems before. Although I have different hardware, libvirt handles USB nicely and I'm pretty sure this should be a simple thing taking this path.  Then you could compare the libvirt command created by Virtual Machine Manager to your qemu command to help find the problem with your command, which looks like it should work.